# How to add a style tag to the head using angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

Hi I am allowing users to specify whether they want to print reports in a landscape or portrait format.

I was wondering if it's possible to add this (see below) into the head of the web document using a angularjs directive? That way it will change the printing size depending on the user input.

```
<style>@media print{@page {size: landscape}}</style>
```

Comment: you have to use JQuery inside angular directive elememt.append('<style>@media print{@page {size: setByDirectiveItSelf}}</style>');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on whether you are going to be using this functionality in many different places. If you only need it once, then a directive may be overkill.

You can simply put

`<style> @media print {@page { size: {{ orientation }} } }</style>`

within your angular controller, and specify orientation on the $scope.

To my knowledge there is no need for the style tag to be in the head.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ngStyle directive to conditionally apply css. See [AngularJS `ngStyle`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle). The example at the end of the link shows how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had to crate custom stylesheet on the fly with unique IDs, I made it nicely work with angularJS like this :

```
<style type="text/css"
               ng-bind="vm.css">
        </style>
```

(note the use of `ng-bind`)

where vm.css looks like that in the controller

```
vm.css = `#${$scope.id} { background-color: red; }`
```

Hope this helps!